# Does the standard say anything about coexistence of exceptions and different calling conventions?

Tags: c++, standards

Like what if a function declared with a calling convention calls a normal(standard) function that throws? So the stack gets unwound and... what happens is, it would have to... I don't even know...

I would guess that it's all just UB. But that would be too sad. Probably only the compilers have something to say about that.

Does the standard actually say something about that?

Answer (score 0):

The calling convention used and how exceptions work internally is implementation specific. For example, compilers on Linux and Windows use different calling conventions.

The C and C++ standards only specify how functions and exceptions should behave, but normally do not say much about how these features are to be implemented. Every combination of CPU, operating system and compiler may have their own way of implementing certain things.

If you want more information about exactly how the calling conventions are implemented in Linux and Windows on different CPUs/compilers, I recommend you read [Agner Fog's Optimization Manual](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) number 5. That manual also contains a chapter on exception handling/stack unwinding.

Comment: A minor point on terminology: the C and C++ standards use the term “implementation defined” when an implementation is **required** to document its behavior. “Compiler specific”, as you said, or “implementation specific” would be a better choice.

Comment: yeah, but the main, the most interesting question, is the first one

Comment: According to page 43-44 of the calling convention manual I linked to in my answer, exception handling/stack unwinding also is implementation ([ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) specific.